# react-spring Transition does not animate enter state

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm making a Collapse component using react-spring which receives children and a boolean `collapsed` prop. 
It's rather basic, but for some reason the animation when children are mounted never runs and at the same time leave animation works good.

Here's what the component looks like

```
const baseStyles = {
  overflow: "hidden"
};
const openStyles = {
  height: "auto"
};
const collapsedStyles = {
  height: 0
};
const animationConfig = {
  duration: 1000
};
const Collapse = ({ collapsed, children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Transition
      items={collapsed}
      native
      config={animationConfig}
      from={baseStyles}
      enter={openStyles}
      leave={collapsedStyles}
      // onFrame={console.log}
      {...props}
    >
      {collapsed => !collapsed
          ? style => <animated.div style={style} children={children} />
          : null
      }
    </Transition>
  );
};
```

And here's working code https://codesandbox.io/s/459p84ky4
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in react spring?

Comment: What effect you want when it is rendered?

Comment: I want to animate height from 0 to auto, but actually any effect doesn't get applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand `from` and `enter` you are not applying anything in both props, means opacity is always 1 and thus animation is not working

`from` means what it should be at the initial stage and `enter` means what it should be at rendering.

So, you need to set opacity 0 in `from` and set it to 1 inside `enter`

```
const baseStyles = {
  background: "rgba(255,0,0,.2)",
  overflow: "hidden",
  opacity:0
};
const openStyles = {
  height: "auto",
  opacity: 1
};
```

**Edit:**

If you want height form zero to auto then you need to first set height to 0 in from

```
const baseStyles = {
  background: "rgba(255,0,0,.2)",
  overflow: "hidden",
  height: 0
};
const openStyles = {
  height: "auto",
  opacity: 1
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6vq0xq8oqn)